# How to capitalize first letter in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel (5.1) blade template engine with the localization feature.

There is a language file `messages.php` within the `/resources/lang/en/` folder:

```php
return [
    'welcome' => 'welcome',
```

In my blade template the welcome message is called using the `trans` method:

```html
{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}
```

In some cases I need to show the same message but with first letter capitalized ("Welcome"). I don't want to use duplicate records in the translation file.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use PHP's native [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function:

```
{{ ucfirst(trans('messages.welcome')) }}
```

Comment: Or use `ucwords()` if you have a string with multiple words and you want each word to be capitalized.

Comment: Also as a side note, I believe it doesn't matter what version of laravel is used because.. ucfirst, lcfirst, ucwords, are all standard php helper functions. lcfirst is lowecase first and came in on php 5.3+ where as ucfirst and ucwords was in php 5.0 i believe.

Comment: Sadly, this is not a multibyte solution.. you can use mb_convert_case( $x, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8') or CSS like this: .my-class:first-letter { text-transform: capitalize; }

Answer (score 10):

Use Laravel helper [Str::title()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-title-case)

```
{{ Str::title('messages.welcome') }}
```

Comment: This will capitalize all words

Comment: yep all first words if more than 1 good for nouns first name last name

Answer (score 4):

Add a blade directive to the app/Providers/AppServiceProvider's boot() function:

```
public function boot() {

    Blade::directive('lang_u', function ($s) {
        return "<?php echo ucfirst(trans($s)); ?>";
    });

}
```

This way you can use the following in your blade files:

```
@lang_u('messages.welcome')
```

which outputs: Welcome

*You're @lang_u('messages.welcome') :)*

Comment: Watch out with this one as your output will not be escaped this will make you vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @Maantje thanks, but only in certain specific use cases. The blade directive @ lang does not escape as well; this way, you can use html in your language files. The directive is usually used to retrieve text from static language files, so that is not a danger. If you want to show user generated input, you should escape it of course.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to make capitalize first letter using PHP and blade.

Controller

```
return view('stock.uk-lse', ['name' => 'djan']);
```

View

```
<h1>{{ ucfirst($name) }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best option is use CSS text-transform property

In your CSS file:

```
.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Your blade (html) file:

```
<p class="lowercase">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p> <!-- This will display welcome -->
<p class="uppercase">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p> <!-- This will display WELCOME -->
<p class="capitalize">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p><!-- This will display Welcome -->
```

Or, the best option for me, use bootstrap

```
<p class="text-lowercase">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p><!-- This will display welcome -->
<p class="text-uppercase">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p><!-- This will display WELCOME -->
<p class="text-capitalize">{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}</p><!-- This will display Welcome -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ ucfirst(strtolower(trans('messages.welcome'))) }}
```

If you use the above code, you can make sure that only the first letter get capitalized even if the string contains more than one capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel get the class Str, with a lot of string format functions.

To capitalize first letter of all words :

```
Str::title($string)
```

To capitalize first letter of first word :

```
Str::ucfirst($string)
```