# Capitalized a blade's variable in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I used to use smarty a lot and now moved on to Laravel but I'm missing something that was really useful. **The modification in the template of you're variable**.

Let say I have a variable assign as `{{$var}}`. Is there a way in Laravel to set it to upper case ? Something like: `{{$var|upper}}`

I sadly haven't found any documentation on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Only first character :**

You could use UCFirst, a PHP function

```
{{ucfirst(trans('text.blabla'))}}
```

For the doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

---

**Whole word**

```
Str::upper($value)
```

Also this page might have handy things : http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/

Comment: Ok I wanted the whole word to be set as capital so the second answer is the good one. Thank you !

Comment: @Baldráni I'll keep both in the post just in case someone need that, no prob ! :)

Comment: Keep in mind Blade is still just PHP so you should be able to use any PHP or Laravel functions within the `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}` tags.

Comment: this not responds the answer, because the answers says capitalize. 
capitalizations means only the first letter. 
so if you use ucfirst function with a variable instead of quoted text youll get a double dot error.

Answer (score 11):

PHP Native functions can be used here

```
{{ strtoupper($currency) }} 

{{ ucfirst($interval) }}
```

Tested OK

Comment: Why would you even comment a question answered correctly 4 years later with the same answer :') ?

Comment: @Baldráni In blade this is not working ( Str::upper($value) ) and you can use PHP core functions. I thought it might be useful to someone - so posted and upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a custom Blade directive within the AppServiceProvider.php

Example:

```
public function boot() {

    Blade::directive('lang_u', function ($s) {
        return "<?php echo ucfirst(trans($s)); ?>";
    });

}
```

Don't forget to import Blade at the top of the AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
```

Then use it like this within your blade template:

```
@lang_u('index.section_h2')
```

Source: 
[How to capitalize first letter in Laravel Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489324/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-in-laravel-blade#answer-46051856)

For further information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade

Answer (score 0):

works double quoted:

```
{{ucfirst(trans("$var"))}}
```