# How to capitalize a word that has all letters in as capital letters in css OR php

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have the following code and using css text-transform property with a value of capitalize or php `ucwords()` I get the title capitalized but when the title is provided with all letters as capitals it doesn't work. How can I achieve the output to be capitalized regardless of the title provided?

```
  <h4 style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post )}}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
  </h4>
```

Comment: Using CSS or PHP? Does the title contain only one word? Or multiple? Can you post any examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower case all then capitalize - pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827377/lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css)

Comment: @brombeer Any, or all if possible!

Comment: In php you can use : ucfirst(strtolower("STRING"))

Comment: @FlorianMotteau Yes, it does answer my question by indicating it's not possible with css but I asked how to do it in css or php and apparently is possible and easy in php. Confused, should I still accept it as a duplicate question? Kindly advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A php solution would be to convert case to lower and then use `ucfirst`

```php
$text = 'THIS IS A TITLE';
$normalText = ucfirst(strtolower($text));
echo $normalText;
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as it's only one line you can do it with CSS by combining `lowercase` and `capitalize` using the `first-line` pseudo selector:

```css
.title-case {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title-case::first-line {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  <a class="title-case" href="#">SHOUTING</a>
</h4>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I'm displaying titles of posts so this won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Twig has as capitalize filter

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/capitalize.html

{{ 'my first car'|capitalize }}

{# outputs 'My first car' #}

Perfect spot to do this, the view that is.

Comment: Laravel doesn't use Twig but Blade

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using twig template engine! I'm using Laravel which uses blade.

Comment: Possible Blade solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489324/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-in-laravel-blade

Comment: @user1207013 It works but when all the letters are uppercase in a word it doesn't work.

Comment: This solution will not work if the words are already in UPPER Case (Whole word)